# Using fancy upload, trying to trigger file browser

Tags: mootools

I am using this module: http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/

Say for example my initialization code as follows:

```
    this.uploader = new FancyUpload2(this.uploader_element, this.list, {
        limitSize: _config.upload_max_filesize,
        verbose: false,

        url: this.form.action,

        path: this.options.root_dir + 'libraries/fancyupload/source/Swiff.Uploader.swf',

        typeFilter: {
            //'Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)': '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png'
        },

        target: 'assets-browse',
```

Is this possible to invoke opening browse window, the same when I press element with id 'assets-browse'? I tried $('assets-browse').call('click') with no luck.

Comment: try `.fireEvent("click")` or even `fileinputel.focus()` as file inputs usually start off by focus, not click - depends on how the event abstraction is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a opening window's functions through `opener`. Use it like `parent`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.foo();
</script>
```